# how can i get past the authentication code stuff if i bought from a used computer vendor

Tags: authentication

i bought a computer with Ubuntu from a pawn shop not knowing that it had this OS can someone tell me how i can get past the authenticate code screen because I'm tired of getting the update stuff when i try to do things.

Comment: You either ask the one that sell you the system or reinstall Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need data stored on this used machine, or the machine comes with a custom configuration for special tasks, it is strongly advisable to remove the preinstalled OS for the following security reasons:

- User name and password of the administrator account are different to your needs.
- Administrator credentials are known to other people.
- Individual configuration of the machine is unknown.
- There is no guarantee that the machine comes without malicious software.
- Partitioning may be different to your needs.
- The OS may not be up to date.

Reinstalling a fresh and untouched ("vanilla") Ubuntu is very easy and should not take you more than 30 Minutes:

- [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)