# bought off lease Dell, with ubuntu installed... need password

Tags: password-recovery

I had bought an off lease Dell with ubuntu pre-installed....whenever I try and update any updates to anything, it asks for a password, which I had never created. Nothing works...help, please? Thanks

Comment: If this is an OEM install, when you first turned off your computer it should have asked you to create a username and a password. Otherwise contact the store where you bought it.

Comment: see here on why it may be better to reinstall Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/381786/how-can-i-get-past-the-authentication-code-stuff-if-i-bought-from-a-used-compute

Comment: Thanks to you...I have tried to change it in grub.....but it gives me an error.....manipulation error and does not change the password. I don't have any dvd's to download it onto a disk, so can't redownload...any other help would be greatly aoppreciated

Comment: @LoriB If you get a token manipulation error then you need to remount it with this command: `mount -rw -o remount /`

Answer (score 1):

[This answer on another question should help you to reset the password.](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/192102)

or  simply try to change old password via Grub , it works but i have gathered information from others , So please see the link first first..

1. If you have a single-boot (Ubuntu is the only operating system on your computer), to get the boot menu to show, you have to hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key during bootup.
2. If you have a dual-boot (Ubuntu is installed next to Windows, another Linux operating system, or Mac OS X; and you choose at boot time which operating system to boot into), the boot menu should appear without the need to hold down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key.
3. From the boot menu, select recovery mode, which is usually the second boot option.
4. After you select recovery mode and wait for all the boot-up processes to finish, you'll be presented with a few options. In this case, you want the *Drop to root shell prompt* option so press the <kbd>ᛎ</kbd> Down arrow to get to that option, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select it.
5. Once you're at the root shell prompt, if you have forgotten your username as well, type `ls /home` (small letters & not capitals). This will list all the user accounts in your set up.
6. To reset the password, type `passwd username` where *username* is the username you want to reset eg. `passwd mysterio` in my case.
7. You'll then be prompted for a new password. When you type the password you will get no visual response acknowledging your typing. Your password is still being accepted. Just type the password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you're done. You'll be prompted to retype the password. Do so and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.
8. Now the password should be reset. Type `exit` to return to the recovery menu.
9. After you get back to the recovery menu, select **resume normal boot**, and use Ubuntu as you normally would — only this time, you actually know the password!

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks to you...I have tried to change it in grub.....but it gives me an error.....manipulation error and does not change the password. I don't have any dvd's to download it onto a disk, so can't redownload...any other help would be greatly aoppreciated

Comment: well @LoriB its better to do a reinstall because here you are to trying to make security changes, It won't be very simple. Evan i have never faced that situation just grabbed the complete answer from others and it worked for them. Why dont you try to make a fresh install after making backup , it will be easy..

Answer (score 1):

If you got a used computer then you need to format and reinstall.  There's no telling what the previous owner put on it.