# Refurbished laptop

Tags: upgrade, password

Purchased a refurbished laptop; love it, but the previous owner has an administrative password installed. How can I overwrite their password with my own to allow the latest Ubuntu upgrade and program installations?

Comment: Since there is no telling if the previous owner put some sort of trojan or something on the system, you need to format and reinstall.

Comment: Is the password locking the UEFI/BIOS system (early at boot) or locking Ubuntu (when you have an Ubuntu login screen? The solution is different for the two cases.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) I think this will help you reset the password.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The Fact is Recovering the  Password and all is not that easy as shown in the link suggested by Lance Hietpas.

Do a backup if items and re-install it , or ask the old owner for password.

Remember a fresh new installation is always better then any other option.

But if still you want to give a try [clcik here..](https://askubuntu.com/q/382746/192102)

hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Does your refurbished laptop has Ubuntu already installed in it? If yes then:
1.Go to Recovery mode by pressing the left shift key (left hand)
2.Drop to root shell prompt

```
#root@machine$: mount -o rw,remount /

#adduser username(<- your name) sudo adm
or 
#useradd username sudo adm
```

shutdown now

Once you have entered the OS, your username should appear to the log in screen.
Then you can now delete the previous user.