# How to Use Ubuntu when you have no access to previous owners password

Tags: grub2, password-recovery

I have an old gateway420gr that I was hoping to use as my computer crashed. I been unable to get past authenticity issues as I don't know the original owners passwd. I can't access the internet via a wired connection. I have tried to access the Grub via recovery mode to attempt to change the user passwd but to only get " Manipulation Token error" message. While waiting for someones response to this question, I will try to read other comments!
also, is there a way to get a live bootable dvd?
William

Comment: And for reasons why this may be a bad idea: http://askubuntu.com/questions/381786/how-can-i-get-past-the-authentication-code-stuff-if-i-bought-from-a-used-compute

Answer (score 0):

If you have a internet connection somewhere, you can download a Ubuntu ISO file from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and burn it either to a DVD or a USB stick. Both Windows and Ubuntu come along with a tool for this, but for creating a stick, I'd rather use UNetBootin.

If this old PC is unable to boot from USB stick (doesn't have USB Legacy Emulation and won't offer USB sticks in boot menu), Get [PLOP Boot Manager](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html) and burn it to a CD.

When you got the live medium, boot it ("Try Ubuntu") and open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
Now use the following commands:

```
# List partitions to find the correct one
sudo fdisk -l
# Memorize the name of the partiton with "Linux" type and "boot" flag
# Create mount directory (replace the hdd by anything you want)
sudo mkdir /mnt/hdd
# Mount partition into this directory (replace XY by memorized partition file name)
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /media/hdd
# Open root shell of the installed system
sudo chroot /media/sdXY
# Change password of user and drop back to live system shell
passwd username
exit
```

If there's no way you can create the live medium, ask a friend to help you out...