# New user, new computer: system asked a password to uptade

Tags: password, users, user-management, username

I'm a new user, recently bought a new machine with Ubuntu.
It's my first time with this OS.
The first task I tried to do was update the system. 
I was asked about a password, but I don't know any. 
The first doubt is: how to set the first password?
The second: which tutorial do you recoomend for start learning ubuntu?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried entering your login password?

Comment: The system doesn't ask for a login password. It just ask for password when I tried to update the system. The login name is 'centrium' and I suppose it was set by the manufacturer.

Comment: If there is no password for the user, please set one in the system settings.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try it and report here later. Some advice about a source for learning the basics of Ubuntu?

Comment: @Hugo: if it was a pre-installed Ubuntu you should ask the manufacturer for the administrator password. [Here is reasons](http://askubuntu.com/a/381883/3940) why it may be better to just re-install your own Ubuntu on that machine.

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. If you have another question, please ask it in another post using the *Ask Question* button at the top. Why not simply look at https://help.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: I would prefer you re-installed ubuntu 14.04LTS on that machine and start on a clean slate.The best tutorial to start ubuntu withis the [manual](http://ubuntu-manual.org/) download the pdf file and you are good to start.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ubuntu World.How did you login to your system? 
If your User Account is previously set to login without password you may try this.

1. Open up Terminal and type in `passwd`.
2. Enter a new password (For a strong password make sure it has capitals, more than 8 characters and numbers) and press enter.
3. Retype your new password and press enter.

Comment: Prompt will ask for current password, which op doesn't know. Won't do

Answer (score -2):

Go to System > Preferences > keyboard shortcuts
run a terminal: Ctrl+Alt+t and type:

```
 passwd user

.. enter new password for user
```

If no luck You can refer the link From the official [Ubuntu Lost Password documentation](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwid9ZWw8cTKAhWRB44KHRX-BfYQFgglMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F24006%2Fhow-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password&usg=AFQjCNG45kyCV2ACY29qrfABPPqbG7eC_g&sig2=3KK_j1gf67olBst43r4zFA):

- Reboot your computer.
- Hold Shift during boot to start GRUB menu.
- Highlight your image and press E to edit.
- Find the line starting with
- "linux" and append rw init=/bin/bash at the end of that line.
- Press
  Ctrl + X to boot. Type in passwd username.
- Set your password.

Please refer the Tutorial links:

1. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall and https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @DnrDevil `passwd user` does not set the password for root.